# Windows Store Apps: measure many pixels a TextBlock width will be?

Tags: xaml, windows-store-apps

Is there a way to measure many pixels will a TextBlock width will occupy?
let's say I have a string with length of 10 characters.

and I have a text block (without an assigned width value), I'll set the string to the Text property of that textblock.

Is there a way to measure the actual width of the textblock before adding it to the layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the only way I got is to create a new -in memory- text block- then assign it the same text, style and attributes as my target TextBlock, I assumed that my text block has a fixed height, to calculate it's desired width to fit the text, I made the following function:

```
private double CalculateDesiredWidth(string text, TextBlock targetText)
        {
            int MIN_TEXT_WIDTH=200;
            //create a new text block to calculate how much space will the string occupy
            TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
            txt.Text = text;
            txt.FontSize = 16;
            txt.Margin = targetText.Margin;
            Size desiredSize = new Size(0, targetText.ActualHeight);
            Rect desiredRect = new Rect(new Point(0, 0), desiredSize);

            //measure the desired size
            txt.Measure(desiredSize);
            txt.Arrange(desiredRect);
            //if the desired width is small, use the minimum default width
            if (txt.ActualWidth <= MIN_TEXT_WIDTH)
                return MIN_TEXT_WIDTH;
            //calculate the desired area
            double desiredArea = txt.ActualWidth * txt.ActualHeight;
            //calculate the the width required to fit the desired area to my text box
            double width = desiredArea / (targetText.Height - txt.Margin.Top - txt.Margin.Bottom);
            return width;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Until any control is added to the VisualTree, it has a Width and Height of zero.
You have two options, the first is this:

```
  var newTextBlock = new TextBlock() { Opacity = 0.001, Text = "Test" };
        RoutedEventHandler handler = null;
        handler = (s, e) =>
        {
            newTextBlock.Loaded -= handler;
            Panel.Children.Remove(newTextBlock);
        };
        newTextBlock.Loaded += handler;
        Panel.Children.Add(newTextBlock);
```

And in the handler make all the operations you need, because now you have ActualWidth and ActualHeight.

The other one is using Win2D, you can do the following:

```
var test = new CanvasTextFormat() { WordWrapping = CanvasWordWrapping.WholeWord };
                session.DrawText(largeloremipsum, new Rect(0, 0, 480, 0), Colors.Black, test);

                var size = new CanvasTextLayout(canvasControl, text, test, 480, float.MaxValue);
```

But this is a more complex way, you can define the TextFormat for the Size, Font, etc.